# Can I Overwrite Task Group Variables When Queuing Build with Azure REST API?

Tags: azure, rest, build, azure-devops, queue

I want to use the Azure REST API to queue builds. I know I can overwrite variables from the variables tab ("pipeline variables") by passing in a body to my post request like so:

```
params = {
        "definition": {
            "id": build_id
        }
        "parameters": str( { "variable_1" : "use_value_1" , etc. } )
    }
```

However, if I use a task group as a step and want to overwrite one of those variables, I can't see a way to do it. I've tried just including the name and value in the parameters dictionary above, but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Is there any new progress with your question? Does my answer help you solve the problem?

Comment: Hi Frank, not really. I don't want to update the task group because other builds use it. What I did is just define the variables the task group uses in the top-level variable tab (which can be overwritten) and then passed it to the task group. Although your answer isn't really what I need myself, I did mark it as useful.

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid that there is not any REST API can overwrite Task Group variables when queuing Build pipeline. A Task Group allows you to encapsulate a sequence of tasks and the variables. When you use the task group in your build pipeline, these parameters are not defined in your build pipeline, these are defined in task group. 
I recommend you to use following REST API to update the task group first and then queue the build pipeline which the task group in.

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups/{taskGroupId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Here is the official documentation you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/taskgroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1